# Fragment in a Fragment in a Fragment and so in with ListView animations

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-fragments, adapter

So, I'm trying to work with animations, and so far, it's been a pretty big headache. What I'm trying to do here is also a little different than what I've normally seen.

The scenario is I inflate a ListFragment using FragmentTransactions on Activity startup. When I click on a list item, I want the item to scroll to the top of the screen so that it's top touches the bottom of the action bar. Not only that, I want the bottom of the list item to expand to the bottom of the screen. While doing all that, I want to add another ListFragment using FragmentTransactions in the now expanded area under the list item. The parent ListView should be unscrollable, but still clickable as user's would want to click the locked list item at the top to collapse the expanded area. And you can imagine what happens when I click on another list item in the inner ListFragment, it repeats the whole process.

Say we opened a multiple number of Fragments, and those locked list items should be stacked on top of each other. I want to be able to drag down on the current one to see all of them stacked on top of each other, which might be a problem with the ListView set to being unscrollable. You could say the idea here is trying to limit scrolling to a certain region.

What I've done, or tried doing, is add a FrameLayout in the list item XML and set it's visibility to GONE. I've set it's width and height both to match_parent. Already I can see problems, because if the relative layout's height in which it is in has a set height of 128dp, and I want the Frame_Layout's height to be all the way to the bottom of the screen, how would I go doing that? Anyways, I also set the bottom margin to minus it's height, to hide it and expand later, so that it will push any other list item's below it down as the item expands. I'm using ValueAnimator to set the animation value from expanded to collapse, but I think my code for that is wrong or messed up. I'm pretty confused by all this, but here's my code below. It's all built in the getView method of a custom Adapter, in a View.onClickListener. That brings another problem though. If I override onListItemClick() in the ListFragment, which goes first, the View.onClickListener or the onListItemClick()?

```
public void setAnimation(final View item, final View viewToBeExpanded)
    {
        // Gets the height and the reference for viewToBeExpanded's LayoutParams
        layoutParams = ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) viewToBeExpanded.getLayoutParams());
        viewToBeExpanded_height = layoutParams.height;
        viewToBeExpanded_bottomMargin = layoutParams.bottomMargin;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -viewToBeExpanded_height + viewToBeExpanded_bottomMargin;

        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (expanded == true) {
                    expanded = false;
                    expandAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParams.bottomMargin, viewToBeExpanded_bottomMargin);
                    expandAnimator.setTarget(viewToBeExpanded);
                    expandAnimator.setDuration(500);
                    expandAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            layoutParams.bottomMargin = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            viewToBeExpanded.invalidate();
                            viewToBeExpanded.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                    viewToBeExpanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    expandAnimator.start();
                } else {
                    collapseAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewToBeExpanded_bottomMargin, -viewToBeExpanded_height + viewToBeExpanded_bottomMargin);
                    collapseAnimator.setTarget(viewToBeExpanded);
                    collapseAnimator.setDuration(500);
                    collapseAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            layoutParams.bottomMargin = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            viewToBeExpanded.invalidate();
                            viewToBeExpanded.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                    collapseAnimator.start();
                }
            }
        });
        viewToBeExpanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: I am also having issues with ValueAnimator within a fragment